# parse server 2.6.5 push notifications not working without error

Tags: parse-platform, push-notification, parse-server

update:

```
npm install parse-server@2.4.2 --save
```

solved the issue, now I'm interested in making it work on 2.6.5

I've had working configuration of parse server, push messages were ok. 
I'm having 2.6.5 version now.

I have this cloud code function to test:

```
Parse.Cloud.define('testPush', function (req, res) {
// Find user
var userQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
userQuery.equalTo("objectId", req.params.userId);

// Find devices associated with this user
var pushQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
pushQuery.matchesKeyInQuery('deviceToken', 'deviceToken', userQuery);
//pushQuery.matchesQuery('user', userQuery);

// Send push notification to query
Parse.Push.send({
    where: pushQuery,
    data: req.params.data
}, {
    useMasterKey: true,
    success: function () {
        res.success('push sent')
    },
    error: function (error) {
        res.error('push not sent')
    }
});});
```

I'm doing this kind of request:

```
http --json POST 'http://example.com:1337/parse/functions/testPush' \
    'Content-Type':'application/json' \
    'X-Parse-Master-Key':'KEY' \
    'X-Parse-Application-Id':'APPID' \
    data:="{
  "alert": {
    "title": "Test Push",
    "body": "Test Body"
  },
  "code": "3"
}" 
    userId="7128712387" \
    text="Lorem ipsnum"
```

I don't have any errors in my log, i just have:

```
0|parse-wr | verbose: RESPONSE from [POST] /parse/functions/testPush: {
0|parse-wr |   "response": {
0|parse-wr |     "result": "push sent"
0|parse-wr |   }
0|parse-wr | } result=push sent
0|parse-wr | verbose: _PushStatus bYSCE3SnvX: sending push to 1 installations
0|parse-wr | verbose: Sending push to 1
0|parse-wr | verbose: _PushStatus bYSCE3SnvX: sent push! 0 success, 1 failures
0|parse-wr | verbose: _PushStatus bYSCE3SnvX: needs cleanup devicesToRemove=[]
```

Comment: Have you configured your certificate for push ?

Comment: yes, sure, i have correct path in my configuration: "pfx": "/home/parse/certs/third_distr_push.p12"

Comment: i'd love to see more debug information about this 0 success, 1 failures, but I have my VERBOSE=1 and even "VERBOSE_PARSE_SERVER_PUSH_ADAPTER": true set and I can't see anything useful (